# Auto Populate Table With Date Range SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

My problem is auto populating Table.
I have table with 1000 record in it, but for testing purpose, i need to insert more data.

**ID | PersonID | Date | Time | Sum | TypeID | PlaceID | StatusID**

So i need to populate the database with 10000 records where the date is between 1/3/2015 and 1/5/2015, Time is Random, SUM Between 100 and 1000, TypeID between 1 and 2, PlaceID between 1-10, StatusID between 1-3

I would a appreciate any kind of help or suggestion.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need a small t-sql to do it:

```
--CREATE TABLE TEST (CID INT, PERSONID INT, TEST_DATE DATE, TEST_TIME TIME, TEST_SUM INT, TYPEID INT, PLACEID INT, STATUSID INT);
--TRUNCATE TABLE TEST;
SET NOCOUNT ON;
DECLARE @X INT, @PERSONID INT, @DATE DATE, @TIME TIME, @SUM INT, @TYPEID INT, @PLACEID INT, @STATUSID INT,@R INT;
SELECT @X=0;
WHILE @X < 10000 BEGIN
    SELECT @X=@X +1;
    SELECT @DATE = DATEADD(DAY, @X / 4000, '2015-1-3');
    SELECT @R=CONVERT(INT, RAND() * 3600 * 24);
    SELECT @TIME = DATEADD(SECOND, @R ,  '00:00:01');
    SELECT @SUM = 100 + @R % 900;
    SELECT @TYPEID = @R % 2 + 1 ;
    SELECT @PLACEID = @R % 10 +1 ;
    SELECT @STATUSID = @R % 3 +1 ;
    SELECT @PERSONID = @R % 500 +1 ;
    INSERT INTO TEST (CID, PERSONID, TEST_DATE, TEST_TIME, TEST_SUM, TYPEID, PLACEID, STATUSID)
    VALUES(@X, @PERSONID, @DATE, @TIME, @SUM, @TYPEID, @PLACEID, @STATUSID);
END;
SET NOCOUNT OFF;
```

Also, please try not to use column names like "ID","Date","Time" and etc which have special meanings in SQL Server.

Answer (score 3):

Here is some brutal solution but completely randomized:

```
with rows as(select row_number() over(order by(select null)) as dummy from
             (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t1(n)
             cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t2(n)
             cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t3(n)
             cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t4(n))
select *,
cast(dateadd(ms, cast(cast(newid() as varbinary(30)) as int), getdate()) as time) as time
from rows r
cross apply(select top 1 p as place
            from  (values(1),(2),(3),(4),(5),(6),(7),(8),(9),(10))p(p) 
            where r.dummy = r.dummy order by newid()) cap
cross apply(select top 1 s as status
            from  (values(1),(2),(3))s(s) 
            where r.dummy = r.dummy order by newid()) cas
cross apply(select top 1 t as time
            from  (values(1),(2))t(t) 
            where r.dummy = r.dummy order by newid()) cat
cross apply(select top 1 sum from(select 100 + row_number() over(order by(select null)) as sum
            from (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t1(n)
             cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t2(n)
             cross join (values(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1),(1))t3(n)) t
            where r.dummy = r.dummy order by newid()) casu
cross apply(select top 1 dateadd(dd, s -1, '20150103') as date
            from  (values(1),(2),(3))s(s) 
            where r.dummy = r.dummy order by newid()) cad
```

Fiddle http://sqlfiddle.com/#!6/9eecb7db59d16c80417c72d1/892

Answer (score 2):

One is to use the pseudo random values derived from NEWID.  You didn't mention how ID and PersonID should be assigned but the ROW_NUMBER value returned by the CTE could be used for that if you need incremental values.

```
WITH 
    t4 AS (SELECT n FROM (VALUES(0),(0),(0),(0)) t(n))
    ,t256 AS (SELECT 0 AS n FROM t4 AS a CROSS JOIN t4 AS b CROSS JOIN t4 AS c CROSS JOIN t4 AS d)
    ,t16M AS (SELECT ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY (a.n)) AS num FROM t256 AS a CROSS JOIN t256 AS b CROSS JOIN t256 AS c)
SELECT 
     DATEADD(day, CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary(1)) AS int) % 3, '20150103') AS Date
    ,DATEADD(millisecond, CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary(4)) AS int), CAST('' AS time)) AS Time
    ,(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary(3)) AS int) % 900) + 100 AS [Sum]
    ,(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary(3)) AS int) % 2) + 1 AS TypeID
    ,(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary(3)) AS int) % 10) + 1 AS PlaceID
    ,(CAST(CAST(NEWID() AS varbinary(3)) AS int) % 3) + 1 AS StatisID
FROM t16M
WHERE num <= 10000;
```